# How to echo an array in a variable in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to echo setting

```
    $this->settings['numberofwordsexcerpt'] = array(
        'title'   => __( 'Number of Words' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'Please enter here the number of words you want the latest posts on index to have.' ),
        'std'     => '25',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'section' => 'general'
    );
```

into this function in variable `$word_limit`

```
add_action('the_excerpt','limit_the_content'); 
function limit_the_content($content){
 $word_limit = $this->settings['numberofwordsexcerpt']; // HERE I AM TRYING to echo it
```

BUT doesn't work, I get the error

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
     $words = explode(' ', $content); return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit)); }
```

I also tried with

```
$word_limit = $settings['numberofwordsexcerpt'];
```

And i get an error related to the fact that the variable `$settings` is not defined...
Also tried

```
$word_limit = ?> <?php echo $settings['numberofwordsexcerpt']; ?>
```

and get an error related to `";",` tried deleting that and still error remains. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $settings = get_option('mytheme_options'); 

    $word_limit  = $settings['numberofwordsexcerpt']; 

echo $word_limit;
```

Comment: Yep, i also needed to do `$settings = get_option('mytheme_options');`

Comment: Yes it did, could not mark it because of the time. Thank you again for your help it's much appreciated.